# Get HTML between two tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, scrape

trying to fetch some html sources from a internal forum.
Just to be independent we play around with nodejs, express and similar.

When I open up the page directly I get the following html back:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />
    <meta name="description" content="myForum" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <title>myForum</title>
</head>

<body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top" width="100%">
                    <center>
                        <h1><img class="banner" src=
                        "./img/myForum.jpg" width="730"
                        height="117" border="0" alt="myForum" /></h1>
                    </center>
                    <hr />

                    <center>
                        [ <a href="answer.php?id=975710">Antworten</a> ]&nbsp;&nbsp;[
                        <a href="index.php">Forum</a> ]&nbsp;&nbsp;[ <a href=
                        "newEntries.php">Neue Beitr&auml;ge</a> ]
                    </center>
                    <hr />

                    <h1>sCHween</h1>geschrieben von&nbsp;<font color=
                    "#FFFFFF">User1</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;am&nbsp;18.06.2014&nbsp;um&nbsp;21:26:15
                    <hr />
                    This is my text! It could contain images and links!
                    <img src="http://images.google.ch/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo11w.png" /><br />
                    <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
                    <br />
                    <hr />
                    <b>Antworten:</b><br />
                    <a href="thread.php?id=9752">Re:
                    sCHween</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<b><font color=
                    "#FFFFFF">User2</font></b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;18.06.2014&nbsp;22:56:27<br />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="showentry.php?id=9756">Re:
                    sCHween</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<b><font color=
                    "#FFFFFF">User2</font></b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;18.06.2014&nbsp;23:14:44<br />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="showentry.php?id=9753">Re:
                    sCHween</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<b><font color=
                    "#FFFFFF">User1</font></b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;18.06.2014&nbsp;23:02:21<br />
                    <a href="showentry.php?id=975713">Re:
                    sCHween</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<b><font color=
                    "#FFFFFF">User1</font></b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;18.06.2014&nbsp;21:46:13<br />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="showentry.php?id=9720">Re:
                    sCHween</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<b><font color=
                    "#FFFFFF">User3</font></b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;18.06.2014&nbsp;22:22:25<br />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="showentry.php?id=9755">Re:
                    sCHween</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<b><font color=
                    "#FFFFFF">User4</font></b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;18.06.2014&nbsp;21:52:51<br />
                    <hr />
                    <span>
                        <a href="answer.php?id=975">Antworten</a><br />
                        <a href="recent.php">Neue Beitr&auml;ge</a><br />
                    </span>
                    <hr />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

What we want to get out is the html source of the things between the two hr tags:

```
This is my text! It could contain images and links!
<img src="http://images.google.ch/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo11w.png" /><br />
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
```

Is there an easy way to get the source between the two hr tags or what would be the cleanest and easiest way to extract this content?

Comment: Why don't you put it in the `div` or `span` and give it a name?

Comment: Cause it is an already freezed product and we can not change the source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Sure if this is what you want:

Jquery:

```
var AllContent = $("td").contents();
var hrCount = 0;
var addContent = false;
var result="";
AllContent.each(function(){
    if ($(this).prop('tagName') == "HR"){
        hrCount++;
        if (hrCount ==3){
            addContent = true;
        }
        if (hrCount ==4){
            addContent = false;
        }
    }else{
        if(addContent){
            if (typeof $(this).html() != "undefined"){
                result+=$(this)[0].outerHTML;
            }else{
                result+=$(this).text();
           }
       }
    }   

});

alert(result);
```

Must be a cleaner solution...

Comment: No it is not exactly what I need. To write in some pseudo slang: $('hr')[1].until($('hr')[2]).getHtml(). Means searching for a given hr tag and get the the full html source until the next hr tag

Comment: The above code will give you the full html source between any <hr> tags, if you need only the html between the third and the fourth <hr>  
    var contentTags = $("hr").eq(2).nextUntil("hr");
    contentTags.each(function(){
        console.log("print -- " + $(this)[0].outerHTML);   
    });

Comment: I just need the html between third and fourth <hr>. with you example of contentTags the result is only <br> but it should conaints the "plain text" too?

Comment: sorry to late for the right one to be passed by an edit. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/44S3H/6/

Answer (score 0):

[jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) is a great tool to do DOM parsing in node. Since you want both text nodes and regular elements converted into a string, we have to differentiate between both:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

jsdom.env(
  'http://example.com',
  ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'],
  function (errors, window) {
    var $hr = window.$('hr'),
        node = $hr.get(2).nextSibling,
        endNode = $hr.get(3),
        html = '';

    while (node && node !== endNode) {
        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            html += node.textContent;
        } else {
            html += node.outerHTML;
        }
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }

  }
);
```

Now `html` has the following value:

```
This is my text! It could contain images and links!
<img src="http://images.google.ch/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo11w.png"><br>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
<br>
```

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Passing the nextUntil which kind of object I get back? Means playing around I see that I get as answer [object Object] but I have no clue how to proceed.

Comment: @sCHween It should be a jQuery object. What exactly do you need, the html? Try `content.map(function () { return window.$(this).html() })` to get an array of strings.

Comment: No clue why I can't edit the above but it should be `content.map(function () { return window.$(this).html() }).get()`

Comment: I want to get the html in between. (see the second grayed box in my initial post) As you already posted in your answer the things from the second to the third hr tag.

Comment: the map is empty if I try your second proposal.

Comment: I was a bit surprised that jQuery ignores text nodes, but after a tinkering a bit it seems I have now found a solution. Answer updated, here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bN72T/